# Mongodb not returning from query calls

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue with my current mongodb deployment. It seems like when mongo is under load, sometimes it will randomly get into a state where it doesn't return from query calls. I have to restart the node server (which reestablishes connection with mongo) to fix this.

Mongo doesn't throw any errors when this is happening, so there is no way to detect this bug. I've been profiling the database, but it says all my queries returns in under 5 seconds, so I don't think this is a case of unoptimized queries.

Do you guys have any other ideas as to what would cause mongodb to not return from any queries?